# Hourly extract of Power Automate cloud flows runs history for reporting into PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, dataverse, power-automate-custom-connector

Is it possible to automate the export of Power Automate cloud flow runs history so that it is available for reporting in a powerBI dashboard, on an hourly basis?

I'm aware of:

1. Manual csv export from the admin console (with limitations on number of rows and days)
2. Automated daily export to Azure Datalake (still in preview): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/self-service-analytics
3. PowerShell script to automate the extraction by looping on all environments and all flows: https://mytrial365.com/2022/10/24/export-power-automate-run-using-powershell-script/

The manual (1) and automated (2) export do not meet requirements (hourly extraction) and the PowerShell script (3) seems like a brittle and difficult solution to maintain. What would be a good way to export Cloud flow runs history to PowerBI?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this post - https://2die4it.com/2020/07/08/custom-connector-to-get-flow-run-history/ it explains on how to create a custom connector to extract flow runs. And then you can create another flow to export this information and send it wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the same API as the "PowerShell" script solution, which requires looping on all flows and extracting the run for each flow. I guess we're going to have to implement something like this in the end.